# How to remove request header from chromium browser c#?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, chromium, cefsharp

I have implemented a chromium browser in Windows Form but its showing the request header I have already tried many solutions but it didn't work. Please suggest me the solution to remove it. Thanks in advance.
Following header I am getting in browser:

abc Portal html, body, body.sidebars `{ width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;} document.domain = "abc.com"; $(function(){ var flashvars = { tcpHost: "abc.com", tcpPort: "8000", sessionKey: "ae5563e0facxkyscsfac0f80d", lang: "en", abcIdentificationNumber: "504" }; var params = { base: "***url***" }; $.ajax({ type: "GET", crossDomain: "false", url: "init/init_flash.js", dataType: "script", contentType: "text/plain", success: function() { initFlash(flashvars, params); } }); }); #flashContent {visibility:hidden}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I have found my solution. I was missing the file during deployment "cef.pak"